# Как реализовать на select'е?

Tags: css3, html5

Как реализовать такую стрелку на select'е?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откройте тот сайт, скриншот с которого вы сделали, да посмотрите в инспекторе как там эта стрелка сделана

Comment: с psd макета снимок

Comment: Тогда предположу, что автор макета не подразумевал попиксельное перерисовывание стрелки; скорее всего, имеется в виду обычный `<select>`, в котором автоматически добавляется треугольник со стилями операционной системы, уточните у него если есть возможность

Comment: через жирквери.

Comment: Вообще есть предположение, что автор макета может не знать и сильно удивиться, когда узнает, что нарисовать произвольный треугольничек вообще можно :) Так что я всё ещё рекомендую уточнить у него, что именно надо

Comment: @andreymal, или не уточнять, пока он не узнал об этом)))

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться плагином [select2](https://select2.github.io/), который добавляет классы к селекту, и потом застилить с помощью css

Answer (score 1):

Можно кастомно сделать, как один из вариантов:

```js
$('.select').each(function(){
  // Variables
  var $this = $(this),
      selectOption = $this.find('option'),
      selectOptionLength = selectOption.length,
      selectedOption = selectOption.filter(':selected'),
      dur = 500;

  $this.hide();
  // Wrap all in select box
  $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
  // Style box
  $('<div>',{
    class: 'select__gap',
    text: selectedOption.text()
  }).insertAfter($this);

  var selectGap = $this.next('.select__gap'),
      caret = selectGap.find('.caret');
  // Add ul list
  $('<ul>',{
    class: 'select__list'
  }).insertAfter(selectGap);  

  var selectList = selectGap.next('.select__list');
  // Add li - option items
  for(var i = 0; i < selectOptionLength; i++){
    $('<li>',{
      class: 'select__item',
      html: $('<span>',{
        text: selectOption.eq(i).text()
      })    
    })
      .attr('data-value', selectOption.eq(i).val())
      .appendTo(selectList);
  }
  // Find all items
  var selectItem = selectList.find('li');

  selectList.slideUp(0);
  selectGap.on('click', function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('on')){
      $(this).addClass('on');
      selectList.slideDown(dur);

      selectItem.on('click', function(){
        var chooseItem = $(this).data('value');

        $('select').val(chooseItem).attr('selected', 'selected');
        selectGap.text($(this).find('span').text());

        selectList.slideUp(dur);
        selectGap.removeClass('on');
      });

    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('on');
      selectList.slideUp(dur);
    }
  });  

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #2b3a46;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.select-wrap {
  padding: 1rem;
}

label {
  color: #fff;
}

.select__list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border:1px solid #777;
}

.select {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.select__gap {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.select__gap:before{
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  border:1px solid #777;
  border-radius:1px;
  cursor:pointer;
  
}
.select__gap:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid #000;
    -webkit-transition: all .27s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .27s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .27s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<!-- Customn select -->
  <div class="select-wrap">
    <label for="selectId">Your Language: </label>
    <select name="select-box" id="selectId" class="select">
      <option value="item-1" name="value" selected>item-1</option>
      <option value="item-2" name="value">item-2</option>
      <option value="item-3" name="value">item-3</option>
      <option value="item-4" name="value">item-4</option>
      <option value="item-5" name="value">item-5</option>
      <option value="item-6" name="value">item-6</option>
    </select>    
  </div>
```

А можно использовать плагин (в гугле легко ищется [select jquery plugin](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=select%20jquery%20plugin&oq=select%20jquery%20plugin&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j0l4.422j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)).

Например, самый популярный [select2](https://select2.org/):

```js
$('select').select2();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #2b3a46;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.select-wrap {
  padding: 1rem;
}

label {
  color: #fff;
}


.select2-container {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 200px !important;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
  border: none !important;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
  background: #ccc;
  border:1px solid #777;
}


.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b{
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="select-wrap">
    <label for="selectId">Your Language: </label>
    <select name="select-box" id="selectId" class="select">
      <option value="item-1" name="value" selected>item-1</option>
      <option value="item-2" name="value">item-2</option>
      <option value="item-3" name="value">item-3</option>
      <option value="item-4" name="value">item-4</option>
      <option value="item-5" name="value">item-5</option>
      <option value="item-6" name="value">item-6</option>
    </select>    
  </div>
```

Comment: спасибо, отличное предложение на jquery!

Answer (score 1):

только в IE не проверял, у меня его просто нет

```css
select {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 34px;
  /*убираешь иконку до дефолту*/
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none; 
  appearance: none;
  /*задаешь бекграунд ту икону которую хочешь и регулируешь позишеном*/
  background: url(https://get.wallhere.com/photo/sunlight-landscape-forest-waterfall-water-nature-reflection-green-river-jungle-stream-rainforest-tree-watercourse-vegetation-woodland-habitat-natural-environment-body-of-water-old-growth-forest-water-feature-255589.jpg) no-repeat;

  background-position-x: 110px;
}
```

```html
<select name="sdsd" id="">sdsdsd
        <option value="">Выбор один</option>
        <option value="">Выбор два</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Эта штука делается несколько сложнее.

Comment: я видел выше в ответах, просто решил отобразить и свой простой вариант, вдруг, кому-то когда-то...))) там минус единственный, что, высота иконки не должна превышать  width select`а....

Comment: Минус в том, что в IE поверх этой штуки рисуется стандартный элемент - вот скрин из IE11: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bTwG.png. А ведь IE10+ и Edge поддерживают стилизацию через [`-ms-expand`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/-ms-expand). Другие ответы все со скриптами :( Стилизовать стрелку без скриптов можно для большинства браузеров, но там сложнее конструкция.

Comment: Можно было бы догадаться, ))) ох уж этот IE...  у меня аллергия на него))...  я чувствовал, по этому сразу отметил тот факт, что на IE не проверял...

Answer (score 0):

> с psd макета снимок

Это скриншот стандартной стрелки, которая была весьма популярна некоторое время назад. Вероятно, надо оставить select со стандартной стрелочкой и ничего с ним не делать.